# php mvc routing regex named parameters

Tags: php, regex

i am developing my own mvc framework and i am stack on the routes

so far i have implement the basic route but now i want to have named parameters

```
routes.php
return array(
    "/users" => 'users@index',  
    "/users/{id}" => 'users@view',
}
```

i need to have named parameters but i can not find the right regex

What i need to achieve is the following

```
"/users/{id:[0-9]}" => 'users@view'

(users@view is the controller@action)
```

so the when the url is /users/23 the route must return id=23 etc

of course the id is just an example and the idea is to have the name of the parameter and the regex rule for this parameter

I don't how to syntax the rule so i can have named parameters and of course the regex to make the match and return parameters

Does anyone has any idea where to start

Comment: Have you considered inspecting the codebases of other popular PHP frameworks to see what they do to support this functionality?

Comment: to be honest yes, but most of them have a router class that is static class with add method with parameters and chaining methods and i have a simple array for define the routes that is already working but i really need the named parameters and the problem is the regex (considering that what i want can be done with regex)

Comment: Well, I don't see how you will get named parameters without implementing some type of router class that will parse the routes.

Comment: Take a look at [FastRoute](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute)

Comment: @HamZa thank you very much your suggestion help me a lot.Please answer the question providing the FastRoute suggestion to accept it as the correct one

Answer (score 0):

You could try learning by example. Take a look at other frameworks and their implementations of what you try to achieve. With that in mind, consider whether it's really worth the effort to develop your own MVC framework with all the alternatives already available.

You could use them as a base and grasp the general concept(s) instead of reinventing the wheel.

- [Symfony/Routing](https://github.com/symfony/Routing)
  ([docs](https://github.com/symfony/Routing))
- [Illuminate/Routing](https://github.com/illuminate/routing)
  ([docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing))
- [Slim](https://github.com/codeguy/Slim)
  ([docs](http://docs.slimframework.com/#Routing-Overview))